# Want to change footnote size for biblatex-chicago citations

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, fontsize

I'm new to `biblatex` (specifically `biblatex-chicago`).  I'd like to make the size of the footnote citations the same size as the main text.  Does anyone know how to change the default font size for the footnotes?

I'm currently calling `biblatex-chicago` in the preamble as follows:

```
\usepackage[notes,strict,backend=biber,babel=other, bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex-chicago}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. Also, it is always best to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. That way the community can hit the ground running and work on a tangible example, rather than construct something from scratch that may not suit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a `biblatex` thing, but related to the document class you are using, or a package you are loading.  In `memoir`, e.g., you can write

```
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}{\normalsize}
```

and you are good to go.  But this won't work across the board.  A dirty hack, which cannot be recommended except for the simplest of cases would be to `\let` footnotesize = normalsize:

```
\let\origfootnotesize\footnotesize
\let\footnotesize\normalsize
```

But obviously this will make *everything* that uses footnotesize be typeset in normalsize, which may cause other, bigger problems.  (The `\origfootnotesize` will let you manually call the original footnotesize declaration if you need it for some reason.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\let\origfootnotesize\footnotesize
\let\footnotesize\normalsize
\begin{document}
XXX%
\footnote{\lipsum[1]}%
YYY%
\footnote{\origfootnotesize\lipsum[1]}%
\end{document}
```

For the article class you could redefine the definition of `@footnotetext` (from `article.cls`) in this way:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
%   \reset@font\footnotesize% <-- original
    \reset@font\normalsize%   <-- change
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%
\makeatother
```

And this should give you what you want.  The definitions for `report.cls` and `book.cls` are likely the same, but I haven't looked.

Comment: Hi Jon,  thanks for the quick reply!  That "dirty hack" worked beautifully! :-)