# Use a font size smaller than "\footnotesize" in footnotes

Tags: captions, footnotes, fontsize

I want to change `\footnotesize` such that all footnotes are sized in `\scriptsize`.
I could do this with

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
```

But I also want to use `\footnotesize` in its original meaning for all captions (and other parts) of my document.
At the moment I am using

```
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

For example, is there a way to copy the command, e.g. in `\captionsize` and then change the original command without changing the copy?
This should still scale if I would change my document from 11pt to 12pt or else.

And no,

```
\newcommand{\captionsize}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}
```

does not work.

Comment: Maybe `\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{\svfootnote{\scriptsize#1}}`.  Of course, that removes the use of the optional argument.  For that, maybe `\renewcommand\footnote[2][\thefootnote]{\stepcounter{footnote}\svfootnote[#1]{\scriptsize#2}}`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46197/want-to-change-footnote-size-for-biblatex-chicago-citations.  The final part of jon's answer there, redefining `\@footnotetext`, provides a fix for your problem, where his `\normalsize` should be set, in your case, to `\scriptsize`.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is ok to make caption titles and text in figures and tables smaller, the command is called `\small`. Footnotes are set in `\footnotesize`, as the name already tells. `\scriptsize` is much too small, it is the size intended for sub- and superscripts. If nobody should be able to read footnotes, then it is much easier and safer to remove the footnotes.

Nevertheless, the size commands can be redefined. A little smaller than the original versions might be a still acceptable compromise.

Size `\small` for captions can be set by package `caption`:

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

The size commands are usually defined in `size10.clo`, `size11.clo`, `size12.clo` that are loaded by the standard classes for the document size option (`10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`, default: `10pt`).

Example for `size10.clo`. It defines the smaller font sizes:

```
\newcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt}
```

A redefinition can repeat the definitions with `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`. Instead of cryptic macros (`\@vipt`), normal size specifications can be given (`6pt`).

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small{8.5}{10.5}%
   \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{8.5pt plus 3pt minus 4pt}%
   \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 2pt}%
   \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}%
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize{7.5}{9}%
   \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 4pt}%
   \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 1pt}%
   \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 2pt}%
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \setlength}{belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize{6.5}{7.5}}%
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny{5}{6}}
\makeatother
```

The example has decreased the font sizes and baseline skips for `\small`, `\footnotesize`, and `\scriptsize` in `\@setfontsize` by one half point each.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your document class, the patch might need a change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textheight}{3cm} % just to keep the image small

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote\footnote{This will be in scriptsize}

{\footnotesize This text is in footnotesize\par}

{\scriptsize This text is in scriptsize for comparison\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]